# Disabling @everyone in embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I created a `serverinfo` command for my bot. Everything is fine and working normally, however, when it sends the information about the server, @everyone is included in the roles section. How can I stop the bot from sending that? The code will be under this issue.

```
message.guild.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(" ")
```

Comment: In the discussion here it is suggested that you add a zero width space in it. https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/8ipzq5/is_it_possible_to_escape_character/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(" ").replace("@everyone", " "))
```